# Let AutoMapper create destination objects only once and reuse them

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

In the following sample console program, AutoMapper generates 3 `DestinationAuthor` objects, even though the source hierarchy only uses 2 distinct `SourceAuthor` objects (but one of them twice).

What I am looking for is to let AutoMapper generate only one distinct destination object for every distinct source object, and then reference this one destination object as many times as necessary during mapping, instead of creating duplicates.

The result would be an object hierarchy, where all destination objects and references mimic exactly the ones from the source hierarchy.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;

namespace AutomapperMapOnce
{
    public class SourceBlog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public SourceAuthor Author { get; set; }
    }

    public class SourceAuthor
    {
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class DestinationBlog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DestinationAuthor Author { get; set; }
    }

    public class DestinationAuthor
    {
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static SourceBlog[] GetSourceBlogs()
        {
            var sourceAuthors = new[]
            {
                new SourceAuthor {AuthorId = 1, Name = "John"},
                new SourceAuthor {AuthorId = 2, Name = "Sam"}
            };

            var sourceBlogs = new[]
            {
                new SourceBlog
                {
                    BlogId = 1,
                    Title = "First Blog",
                    Author = sourceAuthors.First(a => a.Name == "John")
                },
                new SourceBlog
                {
                    BlogId = 2,
                    Title = "Second Blog",
                    Author = sourceAuthors.First(a => a.Name == "John")
                },
                new SourceBlog
                {
                    BlogId = 3,
                    Title = "Another Blog",
                    Author = sourceAuthors.First(a => a.Name == "Sam")
                }
            };

            Trace.Assert(sourceAuthors.Distinct().Count() == 2);
            Trace.Assert(sourceBlogs.Select(b => b.Author).Distinct().Count() == 2);
            
            return sourceBlogs;
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(
                cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<SourceBlog, DestinationBlog>();
                    cfg.CreateMap<SourceAuthor, DestinationAuthor>();
                }).CreateMapper();

            var sourceBlogs = GetSourceBlogs();
            var destinationBlogs = mapper.Map<DestinationBlog[]>(sourceBlogs);

            // Throws, because there are 3 distinct DestinationAuthor objects.
            Trace.Assert(destinationBlogs.Select(b => b.Author).Distinct().Count() == 2);
        }
    }
}
```

(I could probably setup some kind of objects store in form of a dictionary, and then manually resolve instances through that, but this must be a very common AutoMapper scenario, so I assume this functionality already exists in the core or some extension package.)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is supported and pretty simple after all. Just use `.PreserveReferences()` (see [5.0 Upgrade Guide: Circular references](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/5.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#circular-references)):

```cs
var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<SourceBlog, DestinationBlog>()
            .PreserveReferences();
        cfg.CreateMap<SourceAuthor, DestinationAuthor>()
            .PreserveReferences();
    }).CreateMapper();
```